# How can i convert binary to Hex in C++

Tags: c++, binary, char, hex

I have been tried converting Binary to Hex

My enviroment is Xcode in Mac

This is my code :

```
string bytes2hex(string str)
{
    stringstream ss;
    string sub = str.substr(6,1);           // output : \220

    const char *sub_cstr = sub.c_str();
    cout << *sub_cstr << endl;              // output : \220

    ss << hex << unsigned (*sub_cstr);      
    cout << "ss : " << ss.str() << endl;    

    return ss.str();
}

int main()
{
    bytes2hex(sha256("88"));                 // ss : ffffff90
}
```

So, To find a error erase the 'hex'

```
ss << unsigned (*sub_cstr);                  // output : -112
```

I used 'unsigned' but I got a negative value.

And I just expected value '144'

How do I fix this code to get a correct value?

Comment: Is all the substring and sha256 code really relevant to your problem? What output did you actually expect?

Comment: What is `s1`? Do you really mean `ss`?

Comment: You know your `substr()` code is just looking at 1 character of `str`at index 6?  What does `sha256()` output?

Comment: As for your problem, it seems to be just normal *sign extension* when promoting the `char` to an `int` (which happens before the casting). Try using `uint8_t` (or `unsigned char`) for the type instead.

Comment: Loop over `str` from last char to first char, building up a decimal value for your binary number "101"->1*2^2 + 0*2^1 + 1*2^0 ... convert that number to a hex string

Comment: sorry I edit my code

Comment: sha256("88") output is : "O6/\220\223\273\216p\364f"O\361#|F\330\310\366`\261f\231\365l˩\306J"

Answer (score 0):

```
try that and see if it's working.   let's say the binary is 1101, then it will be 44D.

#include<iostream.h>
    #include<conio.h>
    void main()
    {
        clrscr();
        long int binnum, rem, quot;
        int i=1, j, temp;
        char hexdecnum[100];
        cout<<"Enter Binary Number : ";
        cin>>binnum;
        quot = binnum;
        while(quot!=0)
        {
            temp = quot % 16;
            // To convert integer into character
            if( temp < 10)
            {
                temp = temp + 48;
            }
            else
            {
                temp = temp + 55;
            }
            hexdecnum[i++]= temp;
            quot = quot / 16;
        }
        cout<<"Equivalent hexadecimal value of "<<binnum<<" is :\n";
        for(j=i-1 ;j>0;j--)
        {
            cout<<hexdecnum[j];
        }
        getch();
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, My enviroment is xcode in mac. The conio header file doesn't contain in POSIX

Comment: Ohw yea totaly forget that, let me see how you can make it work, i mean your code